# How to get my Vcard in agsXMPP?

Tags: xmpp, vcf-vcard, agsxmpp

I want  to get my Vcard from server.
I send my Vcard to server by this code:

```
VcardIq viq = new VcardIq(IqType.set, new Jid(XmppCon.Server));
viq.Vcard.Nickname = "Alex";
XmppCon.Send(viq);
```

And I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403088/how-to-retreive-someones-avatar-photo-with-agsxmpp),that how to get other user's Vcard.But this method don't work for my registered Id.
Can anyone help me to get my Vcard from server in agsXMPP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code

```
public void GetMyVcard()
{
  VcardIq viq = new VcardIq(IqType.get);  
  xmppCon.IqGrabber.SendIq(viq, new IqCB(VcardResult), null);
}

private void VcardResult(object sender, IQ iq, object data)
{
  if (iq.Type == IqType.result)
  {
    Vcard vcard = iq.Vcard;
    if (vcard != null)
    {
      string fullname = vcard.Fullname;
      string nickname = vcard.Nickname;
      string description = vcard.Description;
      Photo photo = vcard.Photo;       
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It not work for me.
it's response of server:

{<iq xmlns="jabber:client" to="myname@sever/agsXMPP" id="agsXMPP_6" type="result" from="myname@sever" />}

that Vcard is null

Comment: then your vcard is not set yet (empty)

Comment: I am sure that my vcard is set, because other users get my vcard(my name,photo,etc).

Comment: Thanks Alex,I send my vcard for server and it work fine.